# How to find out if a function is surjective or injective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I'm working on task which i'm a bit stuck at. I need to find out which of these functions below are injective and surjective.

Let *A* - $\{$1, 2, 3, 4$\}$, *B* - $\{$a, b, c, d$\}$ and *C* - $\{$P, Q, R$\}$

- Let *f* : *A* $\rightarrow$ B be defined so that *f* - $\{$$\lt$1, b$\gt$,$\lt$2, c$\gt$, $\lt$3, d$\gt$, $\lt$4, a$\gt$$\}$
- Let *g* : *B* $\rightarrow$ A be defined so that *g* - $\{$$\lt$a, 1$\gt$,$\lt$b, 2$\gt$, $\lt$c, 4$\gt$, $\lt$d, 4$\gt$$\}$
- Let *h* : *C* $\rightarrow$ A be defined so that *h* - $\{$$\lt$P, 3$\gt$,$\lt$Q, 2$\gt$, $\lt$R, 1$\gt$$\}$
- Let *i* : *A* $\rightarrow$ C be defined so that *i* - $\{$$\lt$1, P$\gt$,$\lt$2, P$\gt$, $\lt$3, Q$\gt$, $\lt$4, R$\gt$$\}$

I would appreciate some help

Thanks alot!

Comment: Do you know the definitions of injective and surjective?

Comment: Going off of Ian's point...

We say that a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is injective if $\forall x,y \in A, f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$. We say $f$ is surjective if $\forall z \in B, \exists x \in A : z = f(x)$. Now use these definitions to solve the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't this be $f=\cdots$ and so on?

Answer (score 1):

The first function is injective as well as surjective. Since all elements of the codomain have preimages, therefore f is surjective. Again, since since domain and codomain are finite sets containing same number of elements, therefore $f$ is injective also.

Similar logic can be applied to check for the other functions.

Answer (score 1):

1.both
2.neither
3.injective
4.surjective

Just use definitions provided by above comments. Note that 3. cannot be surjective since the codomain has larger cardinality than domain.